# Unable to get selected item text from a spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, spinner, simplecursoradapter

In my application I have a spinner that displays a number of spending periods (weekly, bi-weekly, monthly, etc) and I filled it using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` because those periods are kept in the database. Here is how I implemented it:

```
Cursor spendingPeriodCursor = dataSource.getSpendingPeriods();
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spendingPeriodCursor, fromColumns, toColumns);
mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mSpendingSpinner.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

The spinner populates, and at the end of the activity I try to get the selected item like this:

```
// Get spending period description:
String spendingDesc = mSpendingSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

But it doesn't return the actual string value. It looks like a get a string representation of part of the cursor:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@410dfae8

What do I have to do to get the actual text of the selected item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mSpendingSpinner.getSelectedItem();    
String text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("my_column_name"));
```

Comment: This did the trick. I also realized I could use it to get the ID from that cursor as well, which cut the code down. I was getting the string, and then calling the db to get the actual id value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### 1) Well, with will be enough with:

```
String spendingDesc = mSpendingSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

#### 2) but you can try too:

```
mSpendingSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int pos, long arg3) {
                String spendingDesc= parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }
 }
```

#### 3) or

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mSpendingSpinner.getSelectedItem();
String text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COLUN_NAME"));
```